# Kinect classes are not recognized with Visual Studio C# Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to follow the video tutorials at this [URL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/Build.aspx).

I installed Visual Studio C# 2010 Express and the Kinect SDK / Developer's Toolkit. Visual Studio does not recognize any Kinect classes, such as KinectSensor. No intellisense highlighting or anything. I created a reference to Kinect.Sensor, Coding4Fun, etc. but that did not seem to work.

I'd like to follow along and start building an application.

Comment: Did you try to install the latest VS? i.e. 2013.

Comment: If you added the reference, did you add the appropriate `using` statement?

Comment: Many of the samples are formatted in 2010 version. I'll need to look into the using statement and get back with you.

Comment: It's fairly simple, at the top of the page, there will be multiple `using` statements; `using System.Windows;` etc. Simply type in your own `using Microsoft.Kinect` (or whatever it is) :)

Comment: @McAden Then it would produce a compile error, and suggest a resolve...